# Community user reputation reported as 3

Tags: bug

How come this community user has a reputation of 3?

https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community

Is this a bug? I see the community user as not a person and generally has the reputation as 1.

Comment: I found this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77115/eeeek-community-user-got-sudden-rep-boost-how-come as well as this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked about this in one of the mod rooms and the explanation I got was as follows.

[image: ss #1]

In this scenario where the Community user has a rep of 3, it likely got the +2 from an answer which was accepted on a question which was migrated to U&L. The migrated question likely already had an answer attached, which was later accepted after being migrated. In this scenario the user that provided that answer does not have an account on U&L, so the +2 is absorbed by the Community user.

It was unclear to me if there was a systematic task that runs which resets the Community user's back down to 1 or if it just naturally happens when downvotes start occurring on the site, or against Q&A's that do not have an affiliated user on U&L.

Comment: thanks for providing this info. It is very useful.